# Adding Hosting Breaks Google Apps Mail

Tags: email, hosting, google-apps

I will begin with saying that I am a complete novice in the field of web hosting. So I have this one domain, which was pointing to a blogger page and was configured with Google Apps for mail handling. Now, recently I purchased hosting and installed Wordpress. 
I had to change the default name servers and was asked to remove the A records of ghs.google.com. Suddenly my mail stopped working, and I could only get it to work when I reverted the old default nameservers. I must mention that my mail.mydomain.com earlier opened gmail, now started opening my hosts landing page. Although the CNAME record points to Google.
What am I doing wrong? Btw, it's **Linux** hosting.

PS: The Google MX records are already added in the domains dns settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email routing is based on MX (mail exchange) records in your DNS. You'll need to add [Google's MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125) to whatever service is hosting your DNS. The support for the host should be able to help you find where this goes.

Comment: The Google MX records are already added in the domain's DNS settings. Still as soon as I change nameservers mail fails to work.

Comment: That's likely because they're taking over control of your DNS records and, once this happens, you don't have MX records. If it weren't doing this, you'd see no difference in mail flow. To test, change again, wait for mail to fail and check your MX records manually (https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/). The support for that service should be able to confirm this.

Comment: So can it be changed from cpanel?

Comment: Not from the Google Apps Admin console if that's what you mean. If you mean your DNS cpanel, yes, that is very likely.